# How to convert data frame into Python Dictionary in particular way?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dictionary

df

```
      experiment    score
    generation_0.chrom0 11
    generation_0.chrom1 12
    generation_0.chrom2 13
    generation_0.chrom3 14
```

Code:

```
trans_df = df.set_index("experiment").T
trans_df
a_dict = trans_df.to_dict("list")
print ( "Dictionary is ")
print ( a_dict)
```

**Output:**

Dictionary is
{'generation_0.chrom0': [11], 'generation_0.chrom1': [12], 'generation_0.chrom2': [13], 'generation_0.chrom3': [14]}

I am looking for folllowing two modifications in the existing dictionary conversion.

a) generation_0.chrom0 should just become chrom0 and likewise others too

b) Values which are currently as list should just become numbers instead of list

**Expected Output**:

{'chrom0': 11, 'chrom1': 12, 'chrom2': 13, 'chrom3': 14}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict(zip(df['experiment'].str.split('.').str[-1], df['score']))
```

Output

```
{'chrom0': 11, 'chrom1': 12, 'chrom2': 13, 'chrom3': 14}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
result = pd.Series(df.score.values, index=df.experiment.str.split('.').str[-1]).to_dict()
```